# Detecting double backspace event in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I know I can detect a single backspace keypress like this:

```
$("#myelement").bind ("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode==8) {
        alert ("Backspaced!!!");
    }
});
```

How would I detect double backspace that happens say within 1 second, just like double click?

Comment: Keep track of the previous key code and set a timer to clear it after one second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On jQuery.com itself, within their custom.js file, is a bit of code that might be helpful for you. It listens for the "konami" code in the users keystrokes. If it detects a certain sequence of keys, shown below in the variable `konami`, it responds.

```
// Hehe.
if (window.addEventListener) {
  var kkeys = [], konami = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65";
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    kkeys.push(e.keyCode);
    if (kkeys.toString().indexOf(konami) >= 0) 
      window.location = "http://ejohn.org/apps/hero/";
  }, true);
}
```

What this code doesn't do is track the time between the last keypress, and our current keypress. But note, with a few slight modifications, we can mimic their code and produce the desired output that you want as well.

```
<script>
  (function($){
    // Prep our variables
    var keys = [], lastEntry = 0, seq = '8,8';
    // Listen for keydown events
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
      // Push new key into keys array
      keys.push(e.which);
      // See if we need to respond
      if ( keys.toString().indexOf(seq) != -1 )
        if ( e.timeStamp - lastEntry <= 1000 )
          console.log( 'Correct keys, in the current time.' );
      // Update time of last keydown
      lastEntry = e.timeStamp;
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Your approach does not check the time it passed between two key presses.

Comment: I've removed the down-vote (that part wasn't there when I down-voted you) :)

Comment: @JanHančič In your defense, I wasn't planning on providing it. I had assumed it would be clear to track the last time a key was struck. But you were right to speak up :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to keep track of the time when the backspace was last pressed. Then every time your event handler get's called you check that value and see if it is less than 1 second, if it is you got your double backspace press. If not then you reset the value of the last backspace time to current time and you don't execute any code.

in pseudo code:

```
last_timestamp = 0
onkeyup () {
  if key == backspace {
    if now () - last_timestamp <= 1 {
      // execute code
      last_timestamp = 0
    }
    else {
      last_timestamp = now ()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var flag=false;
$("#myelement").on("keyup", function(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which) == 8) {
        setTimeout(function() {flag=false}, 1000);
        if (flag) {
            flag=false;
            alert('backspace twice');
        }
        flag=true;
    }else{
        flag=false;
    }
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/QqXUM/5/)